# "Error: spawn npm ENOENT" in Creating An Expo CLI app

Tags: spawn, react-native-cli, enoent

help me solve this problem I am facing in trying to create a react native app. This is the Error I face when trying to create the app using the command `npx create-expo-app`

```
Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: spawn npm ENOENT
Error: spawn npm ENOENT
node:internal/validators:95
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'number', value);
            ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('ENOENT')
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:187:24)
    at /Users/macpro/.npm/_npx/a712338f43e79bae/node_modules/create-expo-app/build/index.js:77:736
    at <anonymous>
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async run (/Users/macpro/.npm/_npx/a712338f43e79bae/node_modules/create-expo-app/build/index.js:77:704) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```